# sws_scale performance comparison to media players real time resize

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

While playing 4K video user can resize players window - and result image will be scaled smoothly in run time.

On the other hand - program written with libav which reads 4k video file frame by frame and scale it down with sws_scale function do it less effective: it took more time then video duration to resize it.

Why is it so? Maybe because player fps is less and some frames are skipped - but video still looks smooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because most video players do scaling in the video card's hardware. With GL, for example, scaling (or even format conversion from YUV to RGB) is free.

Comment: Thank you for clarification! Interesting why sws_scale does not use GL for such purposes.

Comment: because swscale is a software converter. It's intention is not for display (you'd use GL for that), but for scaling and reusing the scaled buffers for encoding. Think of data-centers that are encoding video for streaming services.